# jQuery UI tabs javascript click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, tabs, click

I am using jQuery UI tabs, but I am having an issue.

My javascript code:

```
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Eat</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      tab 1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      tab 2
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      tab 3
    </div>
  </div>  
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

I am using another script.js file. from that I am calling one click function.

```
$("#tabs-2").click(function()
{
  alert("This is tab3");    
});
```

This function is not working. I want to display some data from the database on clicking each tab. How to write js function using jQuery? Please help me.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: In the editor used here on stackoverflow, you need to ensure code is indented with 4 spaces. The "101010" icon will format a block of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What type of error are you getting?  Can you use Firebug to help debug the issue you are having w/your jQuery?

Have you tried:

```
$("a[href=#tabs-2]").click(function()
{
  alert("This is tab3");    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code you should use

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Eat</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Drink</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Sleep</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      tab 1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      tab 2
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      tab 3
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $("#tabs-2").click(function() {
        alert("This is tab2");    
    });
}); ​
```

You can verify it working [here](http://jsbin.com/agapa3).

Hope it helps

Comment: $("#tabs-2").click is not working, while $("a[href=#tabs-2]").click is.

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by Lorenzo is not working for me but the solution given by keith_c works like charm. I did find out one more way to to accomplish this requirement, as it's tough for me to put code here, you can have a look at it on http://ektaraval.blogspot.com/2011/09/calling-javascript-when-jquery-ui-tab.html

Hope that helps someone..